# Metal is premultiplying texture alpha between fragment attachment & fragment shader arg— why?

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, metal

I'm convinced that Metal is alpha-premultiplying my texture at some point between the attachment `commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(…, index: 0)` and the fragment shader's arguments (`texture2d<float> texture [[texture(0)]],`).  The Xcode Metal Frame Capture seems to confirm this:

Inspecting the `draw…` command's fragment texture binding:

[image: Fragment binding in Xcode's frame debugger]

shows this is clearly a non-alpha-premultiplied image *(which I know to be true of the `CGImage` it comes from— it's pulled from the network and is loaded manually with `texture.replace(…, withBytes: …)`, not `MTKTextureLoader`)*:

<sub>**Inspecting with Pre-Multiplied Alpha enabled; too light on the semi-transparent edges to be correct:**</sub>
[image: Inspecting with Pre-Multiplied Alpha enabled; too light on the semi-transparent edges to be correct]
<sub>**Inspecting with Pre-Multiplied Alpha disabled; correct imagery:**</sub>
[image: Inspecting with Pre-Multiplied Alpha enabled; correct imagery]

However, when debugging the same texel as returned by the `dataTexture.sample(dataTextureSampler, in.dataTextureCoordinate)` call in the fragment shader (using the `0` texture fragment binding), the pixels are now clearly alpha-premultiplied:

<sub>**Inspecting with Pre-Multiplied Alpha enabled; correct imagery:**</sub>
[image: Inspecting with Pre-Multiplied Alpha enabled; correct imagery]
<sub>**Inspecting with Pre-Multiplied Alpha disabled; too dark on the semi-transparent edges to be correct:**</sub>
[image: Inspecting with Pre-Multiplied Alpha disabled; too dark on the semi-transparent edges to be correct]

---

**So why is Metal doing this?**  Is this documented anywhere? *(I've scoured the Metal Shading Language Specification Version 3.1 to no avail.)*  Is this configurable somehow? *(There's a hint to the purpose of this by the argument name of `dataTexture`— I really would like to keep the literal values in the texture unless I say otherwise.)*

Blending is being done with **RGB**: add, one, oneMinusSourceAlpha; **A**: add, one, oneMinusSourceAlpha; as is customary for pre-multiplied alpha blending *(though I'm pretty sure that's not relevant here since we're looking at fragment inputs, not blended outputs)*.

<sub>Using Xcode 15.0.1 with an iPad Pro 11" 2021 iPad13,6 running iPadOS 17.1; and also Xcode 15.1 beta 2 with an iPhone 14 Pro iPhone15,2 running iOS 17.2 beta 2.</sub>

Comment: I am pretty sure that there's no premultiplication being done when sampling the texture.

Comment: @Spo1ler Based on my experience I would 100% agree— this is not how 3D rendering engines work.  But the hard evidence — actual pixel values on the GPU, as well as the consequences of putting a non-premultiplied image on the GPU and it works correctly, but if I premultiply the image before rendering then I get a double-premultiplied image on render (need to do `color.rgb /= color.a;` in frag shader) — says otherwise.

So yes, it shouldn't work working like this, but the question is: Why am I see the hard evidence I'm seeing?

Comment: Tentatively, it looks like Xcode Frame Debugger's Texture resource inspector might be buggy— the RGBA values of the pixels are telling me it's premultiplied, but the visuals only look correct with Pre-Multiplied Alpha disabled.